# Finding if a crit point is a min/max/saddle after assembling the matrix.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know how to find the crit points, and assemble the saddle, but I am apparently a little bit confused on how to plug these points in.

After finding the matrix of second derivatives (I know this is right):
$$\begin{bmatrix}
k & -2 &  k\\
-2 & -2 &  0\\
k &  0 & 2k
\end{bmatrix}$$

What values of $k$ will force a maximum at $(0, 0, 0)$   Now, as I understand it a max requires alternating determinants starting with -

So, I assembled the "partial" determinants (by using the crossing out method) and got:

$k(-4k), -8k, k(2k)$

Now, to me this means that for the first one, to make that negative, $k$ just has to be not $0$, for the second to be positive, $k$ has to be negative, but the third can't be negative. At this point I checked the answer key, and it states that the first "partial" determinant shows $k$ must be $< -4$, and that doesn't line up.

So, now I am here. How do I find the "partial" determinants of the matrix when it relates to crit points/min/max/saddle.

Thanks

Comment: Let g(x, y, z) = kz^2 + kxz − 2yx − y^2 +(k/2)x^2
Verify that (0, 0, 0) is a critical point for g and find the range
of values of k that force g to have a local maximum at (0, 0, 0). Sorry, I am still not very good at formatting.

Comment: your partial determinants are just wrong; the $k < -4$ is correct. Try putting actual numbers, I suppose $k = -1, -2, -3, -4, -5,$ it might be less confusing than variables.

Comment: Yeah I know they are, but why? Its been a while since I have done determinants, but for the first one, isn't it k((-2*2k) - (0*0), this being from i(a*d - b*c), and that leaves you with -4k^2, and no matter what k (besides 0), you will get negative number.

Comment: hey @will jagy how are you getting those partial dets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first determinant in [Sylvester's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) is just the upper left element,

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{r|rr}
k & -2 &  k\\  \hline
-2 & -2 &  0\\
k &  0 & 2k
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which is $k$ itself.

The second principal minor in [Sylvester's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) is  the upper left two by two submatrix,

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr|r}
k & -2 &  k\\  
-2 & -2 &  0\\ \hline
k &  0 & 2k
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which is $-2k - 4.$

The third principal minor in [Sylvester's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) is the entire matrix,

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
k & -2 &  k\\  
-2 & -2 &  0\\ 
k &  0 & 2k
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The determinant is
$$ - 4 k^2 - (-2k^2 + 8 k) = -4k^2 + 2 k^2 - 8 k = -2k^2 - 8 k $$

In order for this to be negative when we already know $k < 0,$
$$ -2k^2 - 8 k = -2 k (k + 4). $$
We know $-2k> 0.$ As a result we need $k + 4 < 0$ or $k < -4.$

Given that you made a list $-4k^2,-8k, 2k^2,$ I now suspect you were partway along in finding the determinant of the full matrix, as this is $-4k^2 -8k + 2k^2.$ 
$$  $$